# CBIR Evaluation on contextually different data

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, image-processing, feature-extraction

How good would a [CBIR system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval) trained on a dataset, for example, DELF, trained on the Google Landmarks dataset, perform when evaluated on a contextually different dataset such as the WANG or the COREL dataset without retraining?

Comment: Hi. You say "trained on a dataset, for example, DELF, trained on the Google Landmarks dataset", but a dataset cannot be trained on another dataset. Please, fix the wording of your post and add links to the relevant datasets and models.